# Why isValid is true but failed to deploy with error 'Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation'?

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment, class

Why isValid = true but even though still failed to deploy with error 'Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation'?

When I run query `Select Id, Name from ApexClass where isValid = false` it returns 0 rows.

All Apex Classes on my environment are `isValid = true`, yet when I try to deploy I get the following error: 'Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation'.

I've recompiled all classes without any success.

I'd strongly appreciate of your advice how to avoid such error?

Comment: That means whatever you're trying to deploy is creating an invalid dependency...

Comment: you have in mind  invalid dependency between classes that have been changed or is there anything else you have in mind?

Comment: Examination of the *verbatim* error message would help eliminate a lot of guesswork here. Please **[edit]** your post to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often this error is introduced when you **forget to include new fields in your deployment package**.

However, it can be introduced with a code only change. A very simple example to illustrate is as follows. Let us imagine you have an org with just these two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void doStuff() { }
}
public class Bar
{
    public static void doStuff()
    {
        Foo.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Now let us say you want to change the implementation, for instance to rename the method.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void newMethodName() { }
}
```

If you try to deploy this class, you will introduce an invalid dependency, because `Bar.doStuff` will try to call `Foo.doStuff`, a method which no longer exists.